# Find out how much cpu time, memory and I/O time are being consumed by JBoss?

Tags: linux

i'm using CentOs Linux.anybody please tell me how to find the CPU time,Memory and I/O time being consumed by JBoss.

Answer (score 3):

As Jayaram Pai pointed out, top is a cool tool for cpu, memory usage in real time. You can find the man page from http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/top.1.html. Besides top command, dstat also reports the real time usage of cpu, memory, network and disk. Pretty awesome one. Check out man page from http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/dstat.1.html.

---

Note: dstat reports the whole system resource usage overview real time. If one process, top and iotop will get the job done. You may need to install iotop manually for you linux distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Use top command or a more colourful version Htop.